# Can someone explain how to scaling up small images for CNN training in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, image-resizing, training-data

I'm training CNN on ImageNet, this dataset contains images that are as small as 96 * 96 pixels, and others are as big as 1600 * 1200 pixels. However, I know about scaling down big images but I cannot understand scaling up small images, how is it done and how does it affect training?

Comment: Scaling up won't add more information to the image, so why would you want to do that? You could use photoshop or any other image editing program to batch-process all images and resize them.

Comment: I need to make all images at the same dimensions because CNN doesn't accept different image sizes. actually, this is the part that I don't understand. is there any other solution?

Comment: On Mac you can use Preview and on Windows you can use Photos or even download a "resize photos" app from the store. Those apps have an option to resize all images.

Comment: @Kokodoko Are you seriously recommending to batch-process an entire dataset by hand using a desktop app?

Comment: Why not? Just click a button and make some coffee while all the images are being processed. But I'm sure there's command line tools that do the same, if you want to make the resizing part of your python code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to `PyTorch`:

Follow the discussion and the link to the `PyTorch` tutorial.

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-do-i-resize-imagenet-image-to-224-x-224/66979

Another option would be to use the `ImUtils` python package.

`frame_resized = imutils.resize(frame, width=new_width)`

The most popular option is to use `OpenCV`.

`frame_resized = cv2.resize(arr1,(new_width, new_height))`

Comment: thanks, the OpenCV step worked very well.